# Run a function until it first returns True, then do not run it again

Tags: python, decorator, python-decorators

I am working on a module which receives a continuous flow of numerical inputs. The goal is to detect the *first* time the array of inputs goes above a certain pre-set threshold value. In other words, I need to run a comparison function until the point when the threshold is reached; then that function needs to be "switched off."

My idea was to approach the problem with decorators as I'm aware they can effectively be used for running a function only once and never again, which is a bit similar to what I am trying to achieve.

In the below case the continuous flow of numerical inputs are: `12, 19, 82, 92, 26, ...`. In this case the expected output would be:

```
Rand. val:  12
above_threshold returns False
Rand. val:  19
above_threshold returns False
Rand. val:  82
above_threshold returns True 
Threshold has been reached! 
Comparison function above_threshold shouldn't be called any more.
Rand. val: 92
Rand. val: 26
...
```

At the moment however `above_threshold` gets called in every loop and I haven't succeeded "switching off" the function using the decorator.

```
import time 
import random 

random.seed(12771)

threshold = 75

def run_until_first_true_reached(f):
    """
    Decorator that runs the function f until it first returns True. 
    After returning True once, it will stop running the wrapped function again.
    """
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        # If f is False
        if not f(*args, **kwargs):
            return f(*args, **kwargs)
        # If f is True
        else: 
            print("Threshold has been reached!")
            print("Comparison function above_threshold shouldn't be called any more.")

            # tried an empty "return" in this line but didn't solve the issue
    return wrapper 

@run_until_first_true_reached
def above_threshold(value, threshold): 
    if value > threshold:
        print("above_threshold returns True")
        return True 
    else:   
        print("above_threshold returns False")
        return False

# Modelling the continuous stream of inputs 
for _ in range(100): 

    rand_val = random.randint(1,100)
    print("Rand. val: ", rand_val)

    above_threshold(rand_val, threshold)

    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: @BemwaMalak where? in the else clause of `wrapper`?

Comment: Of possible interest: `iter(f, x)` produces a sequence of calls to `f` until `f` returns `x`.

Comment: The attempt of solving the current problem seems (at least) strange to me. Why not: `if not threshold_reached(args, kw):` `handler_func(args, kw)` inside the loop?

Comment: @chepner if I replace the row with the `above_threshold` call in the for loop, with what you proposed: `iter(above_threshold, True)`, no output is printed from the `above_threshold` method.

Comment: @CristiFati, I don't understand what you mean. I want to detect the *first* time the value goes above threshold. But I don't want to break the loop. I just want to give an indication on the console that the threshold value has been reached. Only once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know of any way to have the decorator/wrapper not be called once a condition is reached, but it's pretty simple to turn it into a no-op once a condition is reached, which by your first comment is what you seem to want the code to do.

```
import time 
import random 

random.seed(12771)

threshold = 75

def run_until_first_true_reached(f):
    """
    Decorator that runs the function f until it first returns True. 
    After returning True once, it will stop running the wrapped function again.
    """

    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        if not wrapper.reached:
            v = f(*args, **kwargs)
            # If f is False
            if not v:
                return v
            # If f is True
            else: 
                print("Threshold has been reached!")
                print("Comparison function above_threshold shouldn't be called any more.")
                wrapper.reached = True
        return None   #  ? or wahtever we want to return once the threshold is reached

    wrapper.reached = False
    return wrapper 

@run_until_first_true_reached
def above_threshold(value, threshold): 
    if value > threshold:
        print("above_threshold returns True")
        return True 
    else:   
        print("above_threshold returns False")
        return False

# Modelling the continuous stream of inputs 
for _ in range(100): 

    rand_val = random.randint(1,100)
    print("Rand. val: ", rand_val)

    above_threshold(rand_val, threshold)

    time.sleep(1)
```

Result:

```
Rand. val:  12
above_threshold returns False
Rand. val:  19
above_threshold returns False
Rand. val:  82
above_threshold returns True
Threshold has been reached!
Comparison function above_threshold shouldn't be called any more.
Rand. val:  92
Rand. val:  26
Rand. val:  18
Rand. val:  55
...
```

The interesting bit here is that you need somewhere to store the state...the fact that the threshold has been reached.  The way I do this in decorators is to attach the state to the wrapper function.

I changed your logic a bit so that the wrapped function isn't called twice on each wrapper invocation.  This was producing duplicate lines of output that prevented matching your requested output.

Answer (score 1):

Simply use the idea, what you intended to: "switch on and off" the call of the wrapped function. For this purpose we can use a variable of the parent decorator function as a state flag:

```
import time 
import random 

random.seed(12771)

threshold = 75

def run_until_first_true_reached(f):
    """
    Decorator that runs the function f until it first returns True. 
    After returning True once, it will stop running the wrapped function again.
    """

    switch_on = True

    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        nonlocal switch_on

        if switch_on:
            threshold_reached = f(*args, **kwargs)
            if threshold_reached:
                print("Threshold has been reached!")
                print("Comparison function above_threshold shouldn't be called any more.")
                switch_on = False

    return wrapper 

@run_until_first_true_reached
def above_threshold(value, threshold): 
    if value > threshold:
        print("above_threshold returns True")
        return True 
    else:   
        print("above_threshold returns False")
        return False
```

**Output:**

```
Rand. val:  12
above_threshold returns False
Rand. val:  19
above_threshold returns False
Rand. val:  82
above_threshold returns True
Threshold has been reached!
Comparison function above_threshold shouldn't be called any more.
Rand. val:  92
Rand. val:  26
Rand. val:  18
Rand. val:  55
```